# Which Puranas are considered to be as authoritative as Prasthanatrayi in Vishishtadvaita?

Tags: scripture, puranas, vishishtadvaita

While reading the preview of [Sapta Vidha Anupapatti](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=QWcgAxQnSAwC&printsec=frontcover), I found some scriptures are considered as authoritative as Prasthanatrayi in Vishishtadvaita, as mentioned in the book:

> In the Visistadvaita Vedanta tradition, the Tamil hymns of the Alvars,
>   the Nalavira-divya-prabandham, as well as the Vaishnava Agamas and
>   some of the Puranas, are considered to be as authoritative as the prasthana-traya.

Here one scripture is obvious Nalayira Divya Prabandha, others are Vaishnava Agamas and some of Puranas. Now, I think Pancharatra Agama would be considered or all the Vaishnava Agamas are considered? And talking about Puranas, I think Srimad Bhagavata MahaPurana and probably Vishnu Purana would be considered.

So, I want to what which Agamas and Puranas are considered as authoritative as [Prasthanatrayi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prasthanatrayi) in Vishishtadvaita?

Comment: As far as I know, each different sect has a set of Puranas they consider to be authoritative. Vaishnavas for example, in general consider the Srimad Bhagavatam and Vishnu Puranas to be authoritative. Shaktas consider Devi Bhagavatam. Shaivas consider Linga and Shiva Puranas. In each sect it varies. The universally accepted authoritative scriptures are the Srutis. They include the Vedas including their four types of embedded texts - the Samhitas, the Brahmanas, the Aranyakas and the early Upanishads.

Comment: I think it can be Vishnu Purana, Shrimad Bhagwatam and Padma Purana, and there are only two types of Agamas in Vaishnava traditions 1) Pancharatra 2) Vaikhansa. VA followers or Sri Vaishnavas follow Pancharatra agamas so that is an authority although there are very minor differences between Pancharatra and Vaikhansa most prominent one is the restrictions of use.